# Live USB Always Freezes

Tags: live-usb

I have tried unetbootin, LiLi, and Universal USB Installer, but they all freeze on the SYSLINUX "intro" screen. I am trying 12.04 x64. How do I get it to work?

Comment: Have you [MD5 tested the `.iso` image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) that you've been writing to the USB flash drive?

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced system hang at the SYSLINUX screen when attempting to boot from a 12.04 live Ubuntu usb key formatted with FAT32.  I reformatted the usb key to NTFS and copied the ISO to the key manually as well as with unetbootin and USB creator.  Nothing worked.  At least not until I read the [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/130530/).

I was using a 2 gb Kodak USB key that I got free with a Kodak photo frame.  I only used this key because it was the smallest one I had and at least 2 gb of space is required to make a bootable key.  After reading this post, I replaced the Kodak USB with a 4 gb Verbatim, formatted it to FAT32 and burned the ISO with USB Creator.  Ubuntu booted fine.

Moral of this story: Use a mainstream brand of USB key!

Answer (score 1):

1. Some USB sticks just aren't bootable, regardless of whether the data on them is otherwise bootable.  The stick itself has to support booting.

   In my experience, I only have one (recent, 1GB or more) stick that simply won't boot.

   I would try another stick from a different brand.  Most Verbatim and all Sandisk ones seem to boot fine for me.
2. What hardware do you have?  Try booting with "nomodeset" and/or "noacpi" added to the command line.  In the Ubuntu live CD images you can do this just by pressing any key while the little CD icon comes up.
3. Did you know that you no longer need UnetBootin or the USB installer to put the Live CD onto a USB?  You can now just write it raw to the USB (eg, with Linux's dd command) and it will work just as if it was on a CD.

Comment: The SYSLINUX screen occurs *before* boot options like `nomodeset` can be set.

Comment: Oh ok, so it won't be that one in this case.